# For loop skipping numbers in C

Tags: c

I am trying to program a prime number checker in c but the following code returns some prime numbers as non prime. I haven't been able to find any non prime which register as prime. I am unsure where I have gone wrong and am beginning to suspect that my for loop is skipping numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  int nummer = 47203; 
  printf("Ist %d eine Primzahl?\n", nummer);
  int dividey =2;
  if (nummer == 2){
      printf("nein");

  }    


  for (dividey = 2; dividey <= nummer/2; dividey++){
    if (nummer%dividey==0){
      printf("nein");
      break;
    }else {
      printf("ja");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 2 problems: your algoritm stops when one number doesn't divide, skipping the others!! and consider looping until to sqrt(nummer), you'll save cycles. there are numerous duplicates / questions about prime number checking on SO and codereview. Check them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is skipping numbers - because you've told it to!

If you were checking 15, for example - this is obviously not prime. On the first time through your loop, `dividey` is set to 2. You then do this check:

```
 if (nummer%dividey==0)
```

`15 % 2` is 1, so this condition fails and you jump to the `else` part.

Your else part does this:

```
 printf("ja");
 break;
```

I.e. it prints Ja to say it's a prime number and stops looping, even though it's not a prime and you haven't checked all of the divisors. If the loop had continued on to check dividing by 3, it would have realised it's not prime.

Comment: And so the fix is?

Comment: Easiest way is to set a flag to `false` before your loop, and set it to true just before the `break;` in the `Nein` branch. Once you drop out of the loop, if the flag is still `false` you've found a prime.